# Run GUI Java jar on system boot Lubuntu

Tags: boot, xorg, java, gui, monitors

I have a PC which runs Lubuntu 14.10 without a monitor. The user is autologged in. I have created a Sysvinit script and installed it on /etc/init.d. My script amongst other things, starts a jar file that opens a GUI application that listens on serial port.

The problem is that I can't make the jar application start automatically on boot. Java complains that it cannot connect to the X11 display server. However this is the strange thing. If I ssh into the machine and run the script myself with sudo service it starts normally. Also if I have a monitor connected during boot, it also starts correctly by itself.

How can I get the script started without a monitor connected? It seems as if when a monitor is not connected,  Xorg  server isn't initiated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/26610/how-can-i-force-x-to-start-in-a-computer-without-a-monitor

Comment: The question is, why do you need a GUI without a monitor (or I got some part wrong)?

Comment: @Luke thanks for your answer. The GUI is a required part of the application monitoring and processing data from the serial port.  It's a third party application needed to produce the results so not my choice! :-)  Any idea about the problem?

Comment: Have you tried following that answer? Use http://pastebin.com/y8tRZpJa as xorg.conf (edit drivers and other details accordingly), run `Xorg -configure` if needed and add `nomodeset` in `/etc/default/grub`. Or fake a monitor by plugging in resistors :D
I can't try any of that atm, but I think it's worth a shot

Comment: I can see that many people have the problem of X server not starting without a monitor attached.  But how come everything works correctly if I ssh and issue the command manually without a monitor? Does ssh force in some way X server to load?

Comment: My suggestion is to read the [help tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) and update your question to leave out the chit-chat ( "Hi Guys...", "Thanks",) and ask "How can I start the script without a monitor connected?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of troubleshooting and help from @Anthon Anthon, I finally managed to achieve what I wanted. The problem after all was that X server did not have enough time to load. The Xserver was started from lightdm that was an upstart service, and my script started from init.d.

It seems that if a monitor is connected X server starts earlier and my script in init.d didn't crash.

A simple `sleep 10` command to stall the execution of the script until X server started did the trick. However this is a guess of time when X server will start. So a more elegant solution would be to check when the desktop starts and then launch my app. In order to achieve this I inserted the following lines before launching my script.

```
while [ -z $(pidof lxsession) ]; do
   echo "LXSession not started yet, waiting for 2 secs"
   sleep 2
done
```

with `-z $(pidof lxsession)` I check if the returned string of pidof is null. (So No PID found for process lxsession). As soon as lxsession starts, the loop is canceled and the script moves on to the execution of my java app that now finds the X server and runs normally.

Thank you all for your help. I hope other people are helped by this thread and not tortured like me!

Answer (score 0):

You can have any application run with a virtual X frame buffer using tools like [Xvfb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb) or [Xvnc](http://www.hep.phy.cam.ac.uk/vnc_docs/xvnc.html). You should also consider switching to using a language that doesn't force you to have a running X to connect to.

That things work if you use `ssh` to  connect to the machine is not a surprise. Try making the connection after first entering `unset DISPLAY`, or by doing

```
ssh -o "ForwardX11 no" owl
```

Comment: So Ssh DOES start a X11 Session? If so, isn't there a way to manually trigger what is called by ssh login without installing xvfb?  I will try the solution and post results. Thanks

Comment: @mitsos1os No it doesn't start one, it forwards the one that is already running on your workstation to the server via a separate channel (separate from you typing command etc). "ForwardX11 no" prohibits that (and may make your connection connect somewhat faster). X was designed from the start to run over a network.

Comment: I actually did try to connect with
    `ssh -o "ForwardX11 no" user@host` and still the jar ran! How is this happening?

Comment: @mitsos1os Please don't provide information one bit at a time. Of course your `unset DISPLAY` as suggested well, did you have the same result? Other result? What happens if you start firefox or some other X based application with and without that?

Comment: I am sorry you misunderstood me, I tried `-o ForwardX11 no` after you suggested it to see if it actually won't work but it did.... Here is also another clue. I tried removing the script from autostart and also I connected a keyboard on the pc. After I wait till it boots, I blindly type `CTRL+ALT+T` to open a terminal, and type the command to run the script. And guess what! It also works! The script is run.

So it has to be something else. I also tried switching to the root account with su and running it also works. It only seems to bother it when it is autostarted

Comment: @mitsos1os Or maybe it does connect hardcoded to display 0.0 on the host for some reason and it is not there yet when your autoscript runs. Are you sure there is no displaymanager/X autostarted (later than your utility) on that machine?

Comment: Actually you are right. I installed teamviewer. Without monitor and anything else I can connect and have a desktop normally. So the X server actually starts. So after the test with the blindly opened terminal and the command run, I can only suspect that this app needs to be run through a terminal session. Because all the manual tests that I have done, run the command through a terminal...

Comment: @mitsos1os Then just make sure your init script starts after X starts, by linking from `/etc/rc2.d/S99yourscript ` to your `/etc/init.d/yourscript`

Comment: I did... no result... How can we find when is X initiated so  start my script later?

Comment: @mitsos1os You can start your application in a while loop that checks for the exit value and sleeps for X seconds

Comment: Could you please be more specific as of what exit value and how to check it?

Comment: @mitsos1os not without knowing your applications. But I assume you can check in your script for the exit value with `$?`and that it doesn't exit with that value if started properly.

Comment: I have tested to just `sleep 10` in order to wait for 10 seconds before running my java app and give time to X server to start and it works. I guess if a monitor is connected the X server starts earlier that's why the sleep is not needed then. So it is a matter now to check when X server is started (in my case lightdm starts it) and then start my Java app... How about any ideas on that?

Comment: I just saw your comment. So you mean a loop to start my script again and again until it starts successfully... I understand, I thought you meant to check whether X Server starts successfully. By the way, also look at my comment, is there a way to check whether X server started successfully?The difference is that lightdm that starts the X Server is started using Upstart and I am using SysVinit script.I can see in the upstart config file that it emits events `login-session-start` and `desktop-session-start` when it loads. Is it possible to listen to these events from my script in init.d?